# Windows browser proxy settings

Tags: c#, .net, browser, proxy

I am working on a c# application and am trying to remove the ability for users to edit their web browser proxy settings ( all browsers ) however I cannot find a solution on the internet.  Can anyone help ?

Comment: This sounds nefarious...

Comment: Could you expand the question to help convince us of your good intentions?

Comment: I am looking to build a web filter to stop my kids accessing sites however I dont want them to be able to by-pass the proxy.

Comment: (i've tried to find an open source .net solution but could not find anything so I've had to resort to writing one from scratch)

Comment: Consider an alternate, more practical approach such as only having computers in public areas of your home and discussing with them the consequences of visiting inappropriate sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to prevent users from controlling their proxy settings that will work across all browsers. For IE and Chrome/Safari (which rely on the IE settings) you can set a Group Policy to prevent a non-Admin user from changing the settings. (However, Chrome can be started with a command line instructing it to ignore the system proxy settings).